# Temporary Value is freed at end of statement

Tags: rust

I have the following code

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Node {
    ...
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new(...) -> Self{
        Node {
           ...
        }
    }
    pub async fn init(&self) -> Result<()> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Which is called from within another async func as so

```rust
...
let x = node::Node::new(...);
tokio::spawn(x.clone().init());
...
```

which gives me this error on compilation

```rust
tokio::spawn(x.clone().init());
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^------- - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                  |
   |                  creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                  argument requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
```

How do I deal with this? I plan on using x after this. Weirdly this works, and I don't know why

```rust
...
let x = node::Node::new(...);
let b = x.clone();
tokio::spawn(async move {x.init().await.unwrap()});
b.init().await?;
...
```

Why does it not complain that `x` can be freed in the `spawn` and hence using `b` is problematic? Which it does if I get rid of the `async move` and just pass `x.init()` to `spawn`

```
 tokio::spawn(x.init());
   |                  ^-------
   |                  |
   |                  borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                  argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'static`
```

Comment: Tbh, I think I gave some clues to myself as I wrote this. But I would like a good explanation from everyone here :)

Comment: Try to assign `x.clone()` to a variable and call `init` on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tokio::spawn(x.clone().init())` is equivalent to:

```
{
    let tmp1: Node = x.clone();
    let tmp2 = x.init();
    tokio::spawn(tmp2);
}
```

Note that I didn't annotate the type of `tmp2` because its type is an anonymous implementation of `Future`. This anonymous implementation takes `&self`, which means that `tmp2` borrows from `tmp1`. `tmp1` has a scope that ends at the end of the top-level expression (here expanded to the end of the block). On the other hand, `tokio::spawn()` stashes its argument in a queue, to be executed by the first available executor, possibly in a different thread. As a result, futures accepted by `tokio::spawn()` must not refer to borrowed data. They must either own the data, or refer to static data like string literals.

Your explicit async block works because it moves the variable into the future passed to `spawn()`, so it owns the value. The future returned by `init()` still borrows from its environment, but that's fine because that future is not passed to `tokio::spawn()`.